# CSS: A 2-pixel line appears below image (IMG) element?

Tags: html, css, image

Can anyone point out to me why there's a line (of background color, red in this case) below the image and above the navigation bar? Both Firefox and Chrome display the red line, so I assume it is rendered as intended. But I can't seem to find the issue through the developer tools. The borders, paddings and margins are all 0, which is puzzling. Here's the stripped down version of the code, or [jsfiddle.net/bvss4/9](http://jsfiddle.net/bvss4/9):

```
  <body>
    <div id="main-wrapper">
      <header id="main-header">
        <img id="title-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/JaYSY.jpg" />
        <div id="main-navbar">
            STUFF
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

#main-wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid #888;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: red;
}

#title-image {
    width: 100%;
}

#main-navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background: #333333;
}
```

[image: bad red line]

Comment: Can you reduce this to a minimal case? As of right now I have this as "too localized" unless a specific problem can be identified.

Comment: Hi, I updated with a minimal version here: http://jsfiddle.net/bvss4/1/ . Thanks.

Comment: More minimal: http://jsfiddle.net/bvss4/9/ Update the question to reflect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding a `display:block` to your `#title-image` will fix it

```
 #title-image {
     width: 100%;
     display:block;
 }
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/MGUDR/1/)

Comment: Works, but is too localised for an ideal answer.

Comment: @Kolink - I disagree.  I've run into this many times before - where inline elements that fill the container leave a gap below it.  The solution is always either `display: block`, or follow it with a `<br/>`, or wrap it in a block element.

Answer (score 6):

Set `vertical-align: bottom` on the image's CSS.

The reason it happens is because images are displayed inline with text. This means that they have to allow a small space below the line in case of letters like `y`, `g` etc that drop below the baseline and cause the space.

By setting the `vertical-align` to `bottom`, you move the image so that it's aligned with the bottom of the text, avoiding this problem.

There is one exception you should be aware of: If the image has less height than a single line of text, it will leave a gap above it to make room for that text, unless you set the containing element to have a `line-height` that works.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried it at http://jsfiddle.net/nUacj/ - I set vertical-align: middle instead of baseline and it solved the issue. Would this be a viable solution to you or do you need it to be baseline?

Comment: +1. Yeah, this is exactly why over-comprehensive CSS resets are evil :)

Comment: Yep that works, so does Brett's solution. Although omitting 'vertical-align' altogether would not solve this. Still a great workaround though. Thanks ClarkeyBoy!